# effect of pressure in thermodynamic system

Tags: thermodynamics

$W$ = $P_{ext} \Delta V$

Now my questions

1. How do we calculate the work done if the external pressure changes with change in volume of the system?
2. Is there any effect of the internal pressure  on the work done? If yes, how? If no then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You need calculus and know how to integrate, there is no other way around it: $W=\int{p(V)dV}$

(2) the equation assumes a quasi static process (that is, slow enough) in which at each point during the process the system is
 in thermodynamic equilibrium, thus the internal pressure matches the external one. Otherwise the equation is no longer valid.

Comment: As for your second statement, even quasi-static is not enough. It's more like this: during an isobaric process, the pressure of the system is usually determined by external conditions. For instance, imagine gas inside a cylinder with a moveable piston that has a mass $m$. Then, the gas is holding up both the piston and the air at atmospheric pressure above it, in which case $p = mg/A + p_{atm}$, where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the piston.

Comment: @march  I am not sure why do you say the process must be isobaric when the OP stated it is not so.

Comment: Implicit in your point (2) is that the process is isobaric (unless of course, the external pressure is changing too, but then, in that case, the OP's expression for the work done is wrong, because as you made clear in point (1), you have to do an integral). I was just making the point that there are more assumptions going into $Q = p_{ext}\Delta V$ than you stated; namely, that the system and the environment are separated by a massless membrane. (You could define an "effective" pressure which includes the mass of the piston, but I prefer to see all the physics laid out.)

Comment: @march I believe we interpreted the question differently, my interpretation was that the OP wanted a generalization from the equation from isobaric to non-isobaric (even in the second point). But I agree with you about the assumptions, I just did not made them explicit. Thanks for improving that.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the work done by the gas on the surroundings is always given by $W=\int{P_{ext}dV}$, where $P_{ext}$ is the force per unit area at the interface between the system and the surroundings.  For an irreversible expansion, the pressure of the gas is typically non-uniform spatially within the system, so the gas pressure matches the external pressure $P_{ext}$ only at the interface with the surroundings, but not throughout the gas.  In addition, in an irreversible expansion, viscous stresses are present within the gas, so that the pressure of the gas at the interface is not determined solely by an equilibrium equation of state (such as the ideal gas law).  Instead, the gas pressure is also affected by the ***rate at which the volume is changing***.  So, to a very crude approximation, the gas pressure at the interface with the surroundings  can be roughly approximated (for an ideal gas) by:$$P=\frac{nRT}{V}-\frac{k}{V}\frac{dV}{dt}=P_{ext}$$ where k is related to the viscosity of the gas.

In a reversible (quasistatic) expansion, viscous stresses in the gas are negligible (i.e., the rate of change of volume term is negligible), the pressure of the gas is uniform throughout (including at the interface with the surroundings), and both the gas pressure P and the pressure at the interface $P_{ext}$ are determined by the equilibrium equation of state of the gas (e.g., the ideal gas law).